# How to get pngcrush to overwrite original files?

Tags: command-line, png

I've read through `man pngcrush` and it seems that there is no way to crush a PNG file and save it over the original. I want to compress several folders worth of PNGs so it would be useful to do it all with one command!

Currently I am doing `pngcrush -q -d tmp *.png` then manually cut-pasting the files from the `tmp` directory to the original folder. So I guess using `mv` might be the best way to go? Any better ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All on one line:

```bash
for file in *.png; do pngcrush "$file" "${file%.png}-crushed.png" && mv "${file%.png}-crushed.png" "$file"; done
```

should do it.

(Though so far in my own tests, less than half of the pngs I tested `pngcrush` on were smaller afterwards, so color me unimpressed.)

Comment: Thanks! The amount you can compress the PNGs can depend on how they were made. I believe Photoshop's "Save for Web" has some form of PNG crusher built in.

Comment: Most of mine were created with ImageMagick's import command. I avoid commercial software like Photoshop whenever possible.

Comment: use -brute for better compression.

Comment: The [other answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/497316/41229) is now better with newer pngcrush.

Answer (score 30):

Since version 1.7.22, `pngcrush` has an overwrite option.

Try

```
pngcrush -ow file.png
```

---

See [Changelog](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/changelog.html) for more information:

```
Version 1.7.22  (built with libpng-1.5.6 and zlib-1.2.5)
  Added "-ow" (overwrite) option.  The input file is overwritten and the
    output file is just used temporarily and removed after it is copied
    over the input file..  If you do not specify an output file, "pngout.png"
    is used as the temporary file. Caution: the temporary file must be on
    the same filesystem as the input file.  Contributed by a group of students
    of the University of Paris who were taking the "Understanding of Programs"
    course and wished to gain familiarity with an open-source program.
```

Comment: When I was using the -ow option to do bulk processing images, e.g with `for file in *.png; do ...`, I had issues where the final images had been mixed up (some files where replaced with a crushed version of a completely different file). I suspect this was some kind of race condition where the temporary "pngout.png" file was reused before the system finalised copying it back over the original file. To solve this, generate a unique `outfile` to prevent pngcrush from using the same temporary file for each operation, e.g `pngcrush -ow "$file" "${file%.png}-crushed.png"`